# Unable to restart windows service from my ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, service

I am trying to restart Windows Time Service from my asp.net application using the following code but it always return s a TimeoutException. I have tried various ways to remove this error and restart the service but unfortunately fails in it. The code which i am using for this purpose is shown below:

```
private ServiceController service = new ServiceController( "W32Time", Environment.MachineName );
private TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( 35000 );//15000 was the old value

// Restart W32Time Service
private void RestartService( )
{
    try
    {
        // Stop service if it is running
        if( service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running )
        {
            service.Stop( );
            service.WaitForStatus( ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout );
        }

        // Start service if it is stopped
        if( service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped )
        {
            if (!(service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) || service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)))
            {
                service.Stop();
            }

            service.Start( );
            service.WaitForStatus( ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout );
        }
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        log.Error( "Error in restarting windows service.", ex );
    }
}
```

I am using Windows 7. Can anyone suggest me a solution for this problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the account that the application runs under have privileges to access services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Davids comment is of relevance, also you have to check for dependencies to W32time service. There may not exist any? But if it does, it can cause you problem. In case of a 64 bit machine, i would check for the relevance  of 'W32..'

[Edit]
I attach some code sample that at least works on another Windows 7 computer. The code you provided above works as well, to me.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        WindowsServiceManager service = new WindowsServiceManager();
        service.Run("W32Time", 2000);
        service.End("W32Time", 2000);
    }
}

public class WindowsServiceManager
{
    internal void Run(string serviceId, int timeOut)
    {
        using (ServiceController serviceController = new ServiceController(serviceId))
        {
            TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeOut);
            serviceController.Start();
            serviceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, t);
        }
    }

    internal void End(string serviceId, int timeOut)
    {
        using (ServiceController serviceController = new ServiceController(serviceId))
        {
            TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeOut);
            serviceController.Stop();
            serviceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, t);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The name is still W32Time on 64-bit.  Incidentally by *default* W32Time has no dependencies.

Comment: @Mark You got the points there, i wasn't in mode to check from my Android. Those are fully legal circumstances of the problem description in some circumstances. I will say I tried W32Time myself with success. Are the service fully possible to **Manually** start and stop (through Services Dialog)? Could you control other events with your .NET? It also appears that W32Time runs as a local service, which would make me try omit the second argument ´Environment.MachineName´ to make the class instantiation find that account itself (http://tinyurl.com/6xlktbr, msdn).

Comment: Thanks Joanas for your answer the problem is present even in manually restarting my Windows Time Service so after consulting our network administrator i have arrived to the solution that the code i posted is working fine on a computer which is out of our domain, so the problem is is authorization of my account. Thanks for your help.